# How to set .ini in my zf project using propel ORM?

Tags: php, zend-db, propel

First, to say that my language is not English, sorry if at any time can not explain.
I started working with Zend-Framework, and to achieve set, besides, I have installed but I can not propel them to work together. I was reviewing the article How to Zen Framework with Propel ORM, explaining what's good but I have initialization .xml file that has my project is a .ini, would need to know how to configure it to continue. Pardon my ignorance but I am new in using this technology. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware about Propel.

May be you can consider [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) to use.

It is kind of official ORM Framework recommended to be used with Zend.

This [tutorial](http://ruben.savanne.be/articles/integrating-zend-framework-and-doctrine) can help you to start.

This [link](http://www.zend.com/en/webinar/Framework/70170000000bSrG-webinar-zf-v-1-doctrine-v-2-20101214.flv) will guide you with video tutorial.

If you are intereseted in power-point presentation, you can start from [here](http://static.zend.com/topics/Zend-Framework-1-+-Doctrine-2.pdf)